# Finding a Twitter account's retweets of another specific Twitter account

Tags: twitter

I'm looking for a way to search instances of a Twitter user "retweeting" another, specific, Twitter user.

Twitter has this advanced search:

https://twitter.com/search-advanced?lang=en

that has an "include retweets" checkbox. But I've tested it, and it doesn't seem to work. (Proof: try to search for instances where @bakedalaska retweeted @realdonaldtrump. Retweets do not appear in the search results, even though he retweeted him today... see the images below.)

**Thoughts?**

[image]

[image]